# What is a "state" (of a qubit)? A ray, an element of a Hilbert space or something not mathematical?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-states

**Some context:**

In the literature, there is different ways of using the word "state". A quick overview on this:

1. Some say a "state" is a mathematical object, to be precise either

- a) a ray (set) of (normalized elements) of the usual hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ (e.g. Marinescu (978-0-12-383874-2) on p.24) - again there seem to be 2 versions of this 1.a) but they only differ on whether they use normalized elements or not which we don't mind at this point
- b) an element of $\mathcal{H}$ (e.g. Nielsen & Chuang (978-1-107-00217-3) on p.13)

2. Others use it not in a mathematical sense, but in a more general way used maybe in everyday language. This is the case when it is said that a "state" is formally represented by either "a ray of normalize elements of $\mathcal{H}$" or "an element of $\mathcal{H}$".

Why does the difference matter? Let me give 2 examples of situations that urge me to clarify the usage of "state". Adding to that, let's look at "states" of qubits specifically, since these are the simplest quantum mechanic systems. Let's not go into detail about whether one looks at the Hilbert space as abstract or whether one uses the isomorph Hilbert spaces. Instead, let's use rows of complex numbers (and therefore uses the coordinates of elements in the Hilbert space to represent them). From now on, let's call this Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

*Situation 1:* We know that a result of the formal description of the measurement on a qubit is, that a global phase in $|\psi\rangle\in\mathcal{H}$ is not "observable" by a measurement. Therefore, one should consider $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $\psi_2=e^{i\gamma}|\psi_1\rangle$ (for $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ to be 1.a) both elements of the same ray 1.b) to be equal 2. to be formal descriptions of the same state.

From this situation, I conclude (at least that's my idea) that 1.b) is the wrong take, since clearly $|\psi_1\rangle\neq|\psi_2\rangle$. What's more, this observation kind of leads to using 1.a).

Moving on now, we have 1.a) and 2. as possibile ways of looking at the usage of "state". There is one more situation that creates problems:

*Situation 2:* We know that one usually uses expressions like "the state $|\psi\rangle$" and maybe later "$|\psi\rangle=(1,0)^T$" in a text. Meaning, one identifies the "state" with the formal object that is a element of a hilbert space.

This is no problem in 1.b) since a "state" is just that element of $\mathcal{H}$. There is a problem with 1.a), since one would identify the ray with an element in the ray (set).

There also is a problem with 2.): In terms of 2.) situation 2 identifies the label of a state (e.g. $|\psi\rangle$) with its formal representation. Because we can "forget about the global phase" (to put this rather complex observation into simple terms) there is some unease: If one has two formal descriptions of a state that only differ by a global phase - $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ - one would deduce that those two symbols are labels for the same state and therefore must be equal, say $|\psi_1\rangle=|\psi_2\rangle$.

**My question:**
Obviously, the language in some (or many) books is very unprecise and leads to problems in understanding the basic concepts. What is the correct way of looking at it?

**My try on giving an answer:**
Following the described "context", one is tempted to say that 1.a) should be the correct way of looking at it. But then, what should one call the state (referring to a everyday language use which is not referring to a mathematical object) - maybe "physical state"? Even worse, noone ever (not even Marinescu) calculate with rays but carries on and says "the state $|\psi\rangle\in\mathcal{H}$" (p. 26) and therefore abandons 1.a) immediately after using it for 1.b).

What should we make of all this?

Comment: The actual measurement on one qbit gives us a quantum of energy. The Hilbert space formalism tells us how those quanta of energy are statistically distributed. A physical state was always just paper, even in classical mechanics. But it's paper that describes a single system rather than paper that describes an ensemble.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a quantum state?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/662433/)

Comment: artly. Partly, because it doesn't elaborate on wheter 1.a) or 1.b) is meant. Although it cleares up that 1) seems to be the way to go or how this resonates with the aspect that e.g. Marinescu abandons 1.a) for 1.b) within 1 page of text. On the other side, there kind of needs to be an expression for "state of a qubit" if "state" is a mathematical object - just because we describe this with math and we don't want math to be "all there is". So in that case, the linked post still leaves some questions.

Comment: You should use the @username function to notify another user. Anyway, I don't quite get your issue(s) here. Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state), for example? This seems like a fair definition IMHO, especially the first two sentences.

Comment: I have checked Wikipedia and indeed, it kind of made me aware of some basic conceptional "inaccuracies". For a general sense, the first two sentences are ok. But further? It is not very exact. Further down, Wikipedia says that two states $|\psi_1\rangle$, $|\psi_2\rangle$" that only differ by a global phase correspond to the same "physical quantum state". Again a new term with very loose definition.
My issue concerns (to pin point one part of it) is that e.g. Marinescu defines states as rays and then says "the state $|\psi\rangle\in\mathcal{H}$" which now is no ray (equivalence class) anymore

Comment: To put it another way. I have shown different ways that "state" is used in the literature and also showed how there is inconsistent usage (within the same books). This of course, makes me question the definition of "state" or rather - which definition is one that doesn't lead to inacurracies when using "usual quantum information language".

Comment: I don't agree with "Even worse...", because we have a nice arithmetic for computations with vectors but not a nice arithmetic for objects in projective space (i.e., the rays). It *seems* to me like you're getting hung up on semantics here, although I might not be reading your post deep enough. All these definitions are fine provided we agree that what matters are the *outcomes of experiments*, and that the computations using any one of these definitions leads to the same predictions.  There is no "correct" way of looking at things, because the universe isn't made of math.

Comment: That's why - since we usually use arithmetics for elements of a Hilbert space it bothers me that its unclear what a "state" is.  I mean I wouldn't mind if a book uses one take on it and keeps using the same. But the term *is* used very loosely. This probably is "just semantics", but conceptually important nonetheless.

Comment: In my opinion, the answer in the linked duplicate question is very clear and correct: "A state of a system is some mathematical object that completely describes the system at a particular time." A vector in a Hilbert space completely describes the system (not uniquely). A ray in a Hilbert space also completely describes the system (uniquely). Both of them are states. A density matrix is also a state. A functional on a C*-algebra is also a state.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you for clarification. I might have to rephrase my question or make it more concrete.

Comment: "just semantics" is a funny phrase - perhaps it makes some sort of sense in everyday language, but since semantics is *meaning*, it's absolutely essential to nail down in a scientific context. I guess part of the confusion is that there are multiple levels of modeling involved. At the top, you have the actual physical phenomena, which may be complicated and have aspects beyond our knowledge. Then you narrow that down to only the aspects that are relevant to quantum mechanics - your conceptual model of a quantum state - the physical state. 1/3

Comment: It's the thing that ultimately affects quantum phenomena and measurement outcomes. Then you have the formal mathematical model of this state, a *ray* in Hilbert space; it's not the only possible formalization. But rays are kind of inconvenient to work with, so you represent states with elements of of Hilbert space, and you keep track of the fact that some formally different elements are going to represent the same conceptual (physical) state - those lying on the same ray. 2/3

Comment: And then you're careful about how you manipulate these mathematically - how you add them, you're careful to normalize things, etc. Then keeping all that in mind, you use the term "state" somewhat loosely (e.g. you say "state $|\psi\rangle$" instead of "state represented by $|\psi\rangle$", or some such thing), but ultimately, you're really concerned with the physical state. 3/3

Comment: @FilipMilovanović very well said. This hits the nail on his head and gives very valuable meta-knowledge that cleares conceptual foundations for me. I just opened a new question that your comments already provide the answer to. Please feel free to post them as an answer there: 758502.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović You're right about the phrase "just semantics". I've never thought about that; I think I'm using the phrase in it's modern *colloquial* sense that arguing about *definitions* misses the point, when we should be arguing about *meaning* or even (per my previous comment) the actual outcomes that we can agree on.  Your three-part comment is a much clearer explanation of the point I was trying to make in the second half of my comment above.